# Is sucuri and redis cache work together?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, redis

In magento site my client is using Sucuri cache [Sucuri](https://sucuri.net/) now he want to use redis cache too because site is too slow so I also add redis cache in server and website but after that site speed performance is not good and speed is same as before added redis cache.

So I want to know from some pro developer that does sucuri and redis cache work together or conflict with each other?

Comment: What is "Sucuri cache"? AFAIK Sucuri only has security products - the linked website does not mention cache neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is compatible with Sucuri and won't cause any issues. Sucuri is a CDN/WAF and you can set the caching level on your dashboard to "siteheaders" to force it to respect and use whatever caching headers is provided by your site automatically.

*disclosure: I work at Sucuri and you can ping me directly if you have any questions about it.

Comment: thanks for clear my doubt but I have one question that  what is **CDN/WAF**?

Comment: @watson CDN : Content Delivery Network / WAF : Web Application Firewall